# How to add a .xcframework for debug mode only on an iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcframework

I want to add the [Flex tool](https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX) to my project as a xcframework.

How can I add it only for debug mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX#excluding-flex-from-release-app-store-builds

Comment: @matt Thanks for the answer. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @matt for showing me the answer. On this [link](https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX#flex-files-added-manually-to-a-project) it can be seen what it needs to done, the repo itself already shows the steps.

I am posting the answer because I believe it can be helpful.

Steps:

1. Drag and drop the xcframework to your project.
2. In Xcode, navigate to **Build Settings > Build Options > Excluded Source File Names**. For your Release configuration, set it to FLEX* like this to exclude all files with the FLEX prefix:
   [image]

This idea can be extended to any specific xcframework.

Comment: I would add, that if you want to have multiple excluded files  in EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES they need to be separated by spaces, and not commas. Like "filter1* filter2*"